# How do I access my C# Array in my View?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an array in my Controller that I'm passing over to my View, and (temporarily) I'm trying to `console.log` some of the values in the array (just to make sure I passed the array over correctly.)

I'm trying to send it over with `ViewData` and access it through Razor code, but Razor won't allow me to do any javascript functions (such as `console.log`).

I've tried a few different solutions but can't come up with anything that works, this is the solution that got me the closest:

**View**

```
function logValues()
{
    console.log("test");      
    @{var capacity = ViewData["Capacity"] as string[]; }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        console.log(capacity[i]);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
var uspCapacity = from d in db.uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport(option, date)
                  select new
                  {
                     d.Capacity
                  };
var uspCapacityList = uspCapacity.ToList();
ViewData["Capacity"] = uspCapacityList;
```

The console will successfully log "Test" but cannot access my capacity variable.. because I'm defining it in Razor and trying to access it outside of Razor. How can I access it with Javascript commands?

Comment: First of all you don't need to do `uspCapacity.ToString().ToList();`. Only `uspCapacity.ToList();` is required. And in JavaScript you need to do `@capacity[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current server code is setting a collection of **anonymous objects** to the viewdata dictionary. It is not an array of strings.

```
ViewData["Capacity"] = (from d in db.uspGetEventKillSheetDetailedReport(option, date)
                       select  d.Capacity).ToList();
```

This should work, assuming this code is in a razor file

```
function logValues()
{
    console.log("test");      
    var capacity = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewData["Capacity"]))  
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        console.log(capacity[i]);
    }
}
```

When razor executes the above code, it will serialize the string list we set to Viewdata dictionary to a string for the array initialization(ex:`["Java","Swift","SQL","PHP","Ruby"]`) and js will set that value to the`capacity` variable

`JsonConvert` is defined in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. So you need to import that to your razor view.

Comment: This also works! This approach is better for me because it returns the array values instead of JSON objects, which lets me skip parsing JSON before using the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the C# array to JSON and assign this to a JS variable:

```
<script>
    var capacity = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Capacity"]));

    // now you can use capacity like any other JS variable...
    for (var i = 0; i < capacity.length; i++) {
        console.log(capacity[i]);
    }
</script>
```

`Json.Encode` is defined in `System.Web.Helpers` and should be available in every MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function logValues()
{
    console.log("test");      
    @{var capacity = (List<int>)ViewData["Capacity"]; }
    @foreach (var s in capacity)
    {
        <text>console.log(@s)</text>
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get a casting error because when I call the array `ViewData["Capacity"]` it returns `1[<>f__AnonymousType1 1[System.Int32]]`

Comment: I have updated the post above to cast it back to List<int>. It appears your capacity list is for int data type and not string. Please try it again.